# What privacy-violating or device-changing things can I do on an iPhone?

Tags: ios

I see a lot of questions like these about iPhone and iOS.  I'd like to re-ask (and answer) them as a group, and generally...

- can I see the data belonging to another app or change it's behavior?
- can I prevent some aspect of the device from functioning, like wifi or bluetooth?
- can I change settings on the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The whole thing is designed so developers can't do stuff like that.  Imagine if you could.  You'd do these things for beneficial purposes, of course.  But how long would it take for malicious apps to appear?  Users wouldn't like that, and Apple would like it less.

So, no.