# iOS - Preventing incoming phone and sms messages

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm pretty sure this is not possible based on research but would appreciate some thoughts.

Theoretically, if you were the programmer of the Nike run app.  Could you prevent the user from receiving incoming phone and SMS messages while they were running?

Is there a way to programmatically put the phone in DND, disable any features. Hook an incoming phone call and not allow it through.

This type of think is possible in Android, but I'm 99% sure it is not possible on iOS. The app would have to handle it, I'm not suggesting to suggest the person go manually change to DND mode or anything like that.  Would have to be automatic once the app is open.

Can anyone confirm or disconfirm this is possible?

Comment: You're gonna be able to do this, at least not without jailbreak.

Comment: Apple will not allow that kind of control over the external functions of the phone.

Comment: You're first thought is correct it isn't possible, iOS apps run in a sandbox so they don't know about other apps that are running like SMS. As for the Nike app this has special conditions to it that allow it to do things every other developer isn't allowed to do.

Comment: I see this kind of question often enough that I wrote this recently...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620771/what-privacy-violating-or-device-changing-things-can-i-do-on-an-iphone

Comment: I would imagine that if Nike wanted to do this then apple would create a private API for them, however there is no way that any of us plebs would be allowed access to such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible (unless the phone is jailbroken.)

Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to interfere with the functioning of other apps, or of the phone.

Answer (score -2):

Apple doesn't allow you to do so

because it will prevent the Phone from doing it's basic functionality of calling and texting.

Comment: @Downvoter will you please explain the reason so that i can improve my answer or at least can right my self.

Comment: At a guess because your last part of your answer doesn't actually make sense, I suspect you meant to put `"because it prevents the phone from doing its basic functionality of receiving and sending SMS messages."` or something along those lines.

Comment: is it possible that from your app you can change the basic OS OS functionality???

Comment: No it's just your sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: it a common sense thinking, and understandable statement

Comment: Okay fine and its funny too …

Comment: The first part ("`Apple doesn't allow you to do so"`) is correct but your last line doesn't make any sense, they are just some words that are strung together. It's bad English and makes no sense what so ever, so it's not common sense and it's not funny it just doesn't make sense. Just so you know as well it's just `"it's common sense"` not `"it a common sense thinking"` that also doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Zaibi, the others speak truth. Your second "sentence" isn't grammatical, and makes no sense as written. I didn't down-vote you, but you need to go back and edit your second "sentence" into something that is actually a coherent, grammatical sentence.

Comment: @Popeye It was Just a typing mistake

Comment: @Zaibi If it was a typo why has it not been corrected and why has it take so long for you to understand it was a typo?

Comment: hmmmm i was not online man for last some hours.

Comment: Then how where you responding to me saying it didn't make sense?