# Write a program that can play the 2048 app

Tags: ios, iphone, automated-tests, functional-testing, ios-ui-automation

I thought it would be fun to experiment with algorithms that can play the game 2048. I'm familiar with Objective-C development and iOS. Is there any way, perhaps through scripting in the iPhone simulator, automated testing frameworks, or some other method, to be able to get the state of the board and then be able to simulate the appropriate touches in the simulator or on the device?

This question doesn't concern the algorithms determining the correct move, just the ability to ascertain the board state, and then execute whatever move the algorithm determines to be best.

Basically I'm looking for a method that allows you to automate user actions on an app that you do not have the source code for.

Comment: Not doable.  Your intention is good, but think of what could be done if this were possible with bad intentions.  See my catch-all answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620771/what-privacy-violating-or-device-changing-things-can-i-do-on-an-iphone

Comment: Well, it should be doable on a jailbroken device.

Comment: Since 2048 is just a website you could build a simple app that is just a web view. Then you'd have the code signing permissions to use the Automation instrument with it.