# Is it possible to restrict iOS access via an app?

Tags: ios, iphone

A client asks me if it is possible to create an app which control access to other apps on iOS ? I think it's ok on Android, but not on iOS.

Technically, can you create an app to restrict user interface when it's on ? Like for children or whatever usage ?

Thanks,
M.

Comment: No.  Though the idea is well-meaning, the capability would be equally able to do harm.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620771/what-privacy-violating-or-device-changing-things-can-i-do-on-an-iphone/23620772#23620772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. iOS has built-in features that do this, like [Guided Access](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509), but third-party apps are not allowed that amount of control over the system.

Comment: I’m not as familiar with that, but it’s much more likely.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiddoware.kidsplace

I think this answer our current question.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, iOS apps are sandboxed. If Apple allowed this, it would probably cause more harm than good. Don't expect this to become available in the future. Sorry!